# #Binary logistic regression in torch output not change

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, torch

There are something wrong with the logistic regression in torch.
When I use the binary logistic regression to train the model, the outputs are staying the same as follows:

```
linLayer = nn.Linear(3,1)
sigmoid=nn.Sigmoid()
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(linLayer)
model:add(sigmoid)

criterion = nn.BCECriterion()
```

with optim method

```
for i = 1,epochs do
    current_loss = 0
for i = 1,(#dataset_inputs)[1] do

    _,fs = optim.sgd(feval,x,sgd_params)

    current_loss = current_loss + fs[1]
end
current_loss = current_loss / (#dataset_inputs)[1]
print('epoch = ' .. i .. 
 ' of ' .. epochs .. 
 ' current loss = ' .. current_loss)

end
```

SGD parameters is:

```
sgd_params = {
   learningRate = 1e-6,
   learningRateDecay = 1e-4,
   weightDecay = 0,
   momentum = 0
}
```

and it looks like:

```
epoch = 1 of 2000 current loss = 8.7728492043066    
epoch = 2 of 2000 current loss = 8.7728492043066    
epoch = 3 of 2000 current loss = 8.7728492043066    
epoch = 4 of 2000 current loss = 8.7728492043066    
epoch = 5 of 2000 current loss = 8.7728492043066    
epoch = 6 of 2000 current loss = 8.7728492043066    
epoch = 7 of 2000 current loss = 8.7728492043066
```

......
and the output of the model is:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
.
.
.
```

sometimes is:

```
1
1
1
.
.
.
```

and I change the learning rate or learning rate decay, it doesn't work at all. I have no idea about this problem. Do you guys know what's wrong here?

While here is my feval function.

```
feval = function(x_new)
    if x ~= x_new then
      x:copy(x_new)
   end

   _nidx_ = (_nidx_ or 0) + 1
   if _nidx_ > (#dataset_inputs)[1] then _nidx_ = 1 end

   local sample = dataset[_nidx_]
   local inputs = sample[{ {2,4} }]
   local target = sample[{ {1} }] 

   dl_dx:zero()

   local loss_x = criterion:forward(model:forward(inputs),target)
   model:backward(inputs, criterion:backward(model.output,target))

   -- return loss(x) and dloss/dx
   return loss_x, dl_dx
end
```

Comment: Can we take a look at your `feval` function?

Comment: @AlexanderLutsenko I have mentioned it now. Thanks.

Comment: I modify something then. model:add(nn.MulConstant(0.01)) will be added in the code. After the change, it does work now. I think the input range might be too large to obtain accurate answer.